# Flutter: ListView Unique Key

Tags: flutter, listview, key, unique-key

I have a problem with flutters SortableListView:
I made an todo - list like app, where you can add, remove and sort cards with different colors and text/content. But when I try to delete the card, by removing its data from the lists, nothing happens. I already tryed using the content of the card as key, but then I cant have the same card multiple times.

Thank you so much in advance for helping me, i'm struggling with this problem for a week.

```
Widget ideasTemplate(idea, color, bgColor, key){
    return Container(
      key: key,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        color: BackgroundColors[bgColor], //testBgColor,

      ),
      
      child: ListTile(

        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        title: Text(
          idea.toString(),
          style: GoogleFonts.arsenal(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              color: myColors[color], //testFtColor,
            ),
          ),


        trailing: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
          color: myColors[color], //testFtColor,
          onPressed: () async {

            ideas.remove(idea);
            colors.remove(color);
            bgColors.remove(bgColor);



            UserSimplePreferences.setIdeas(ideas);
            UserSimplePreferences.setColors(colors);
            UserSimplePreferences.setBgColors(bgColors);

            setState(() {});
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
            'Ideas',
          style: GoogleFonts.arsenal(),
        ),
        foregroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () async{
              setBeginColor.set();
              final data = await Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddIdeaScreen()));
              if(data['idea'] != null){
              ideas.add(data['idea']);
              colors.add(data['color']);
              bgColors.add(data['bgColor']);


              UserSimplePreferences.setIdeas(ideas);
              UserSimplePreferences.setColors(colors);
              UserSimplePreferences.setBgColors(bgColors);


              }
              setState(() {});
            },
            alignment: Alignment(-11,0),
            iconSize: 28,
            icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.grey[700]),

          )
        ],

      ),

      body: ReorderableListView.builder(
        itemCount: ideas.length,
        onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) => setState(()  {
          final index = newIndex > oldIndex ? newIndex -1 : newIndex;

          final idea = ideas.removeAt(oldIndex);
          final color = colors.removeAt(oldIndex);
          final bgColor = bgColors.removeAt(oldIndex);


          ideas.insert(index, idea);
          colors.insert(index, color);
          bgColors.insert(index, bgColor);


          UserSimplePreferences.setIdeas(ideas);
          UserSimplePreferences.setColors(colors);
          UserSimplePreferences.setBgColors(bgColors);



        }),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final idea = ideas[index];
          final color = colors[index];
          final bgColor = bgColors[index];
          final key = UniqueKey();

          return ideasTemplate(idea, color, bgColor, key);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **key** parameter from the Container widget and add `UniqueKey()` in the `key:UniqueKey()` property of **ReorderableListView.builder** instead of the Container widget

it would be:

```
ReorderableListView.builder(
key: UniqueKey(),
itemCount: ideas.length,
onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) => setState(()  {
  final index = newIndex > oldIndex ? newIndex -1 : newIndex;

  final idea = ideas.removeAt(oldIndex);
  final color = colors.removeAt(oldIndex);
  final bgColor = bgColors.removeAt(oldIndex);


  ideas.insert(index, idea);
  colors.insert(index, color);
  bgColors.insert(index, bgColor);


  UserSimplePreferences.setIdeas(ideas);
  UserSimplePreferences.setColors(colors);
  UserSimplePreferences.setBgColors(bgColors);



}),
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  final idea = ideas[index];
  final color = colors[index];
  final bgColor = bgColors[index];

  return ideasTemplate(idea, color, bgColor);
},
```

)